# find and replace in place with grep and sed (and make a log for the files changed)

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pipe

My script is as follow (variables are defined above by user input):

```
grep -RlI $OLD $PATH > $LIST
while read line
do
FILE=echo $line
sed -i '' -e 's|$OLD|$NEW|g' $FILE
done < $LIST
```

It seems to work except that sed fails because
"sed: -i may not be used with stdin"

What am I doing wrong? Maybe that's the wrong approach for what I am trying to do?
(which, by the way, is to replace occurrences of a string in many files, AND to create a file that lists all files that contain a match.)
Many thanks,
C

Comment: Why are you giving empty single quotes after -i option?.. it should just be sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" $FILE

Comment: Vineeth it depends on your version of sed. I'm using BSD sed which requires them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
FILE=echo $line
```

with

```
FILE="$line"
```

`sed` is complaining because the `$FILE` variable doesn't contain anything, or just contains whitespace.  Examine the contents of the file referenced by `$LIST`; make sure there are no empty lines or lines with just whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Danny. I think you were right about the cause of that error, but now the script fails silently...

Comment: Oh, use double-quotes instead of single-quotes for `s|$OLD|$NEW|` so that the variable evaluation occurs.  And, replace pipe characters with forward slashes (change `|`'s to `/`'s).  What Vineeth said in a previous comment. :)

Comment: Yes! My heart skipped a beat when I saw it working! (I've been on it for hours). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -r 's/\$[[:alnum:]]{32}-[[:digit:]]{8}\$[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]{2,3}@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*/****/' *.log
```

my variant to replace data like $1BC29B36F623BA82AAF6724FD3B16718-17082022$2sy@domain4.name with *****